# Interpret 4 char as an integer

Tags: c, xv6

I have a function that returns n random bytes. For testing I wanted it to produce 4 random bytes and then assign the 4 bytes of an integer as the random bytes. I have something that works but it seems like an excessive amount of syntax for what I am trying to do. I just wanted to see if it really is necessary or if it can be done in a better way

**Note**: This is being done in [xv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv6), no solutions that involve an `include`

```
int val0 = (((int)buf[0])&0xff);
int val1 = (((int)buf[1])&0xff);
int val2 = (((int)buf[2])&0xff);
int val3 = (((int)buf[3])&0xff);

int number = val0 | (val1<<8) | (val2<<16) | (val3<<24);
```

Comment: Note this is swapping the endianness. buf[0] goes from the most significant byte to the least.

Comment: @D'Nabre, Didn't notice, the bytes are random, but good point

Comment: @D'Nabre: on some machines, it would not be swapping the endianness.

Comment: `buf[i]` will always be promoted to `int` so you don't need the cast. If buf is unsigned you don't need to mask either. Better use `val0 = (unsigned char)buf[0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see you are using `gcc` from this [reference here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/tools.html) and we know [gcc support type punning through unions explicitly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning) then that may be a reasonable solution:

```
union charToInt
{
    char arr[sizeof(int)] ;
    int x ;
} ;

int main()
{
    union charToInt u1 = { .arr = "ab" } ; // or { .arr = "abcd" } if sizeof(int) == 4
}
```

Then `u1.x` will hold the the *int* value. I did not add any output since I am not sure what you use for output.

Comment: Great, thank you. I never had a good reason to use unions before

Comment: @asimes the other main use would be to implement a variant type.